# ios if string returns nothing

Tags: ios, if-statement

what I have is a variable `visit.transmitter.name` that will return a name `transmitter` every few seconds when a transmitter is around. What I would like to do is if the program stops reviewing a transmission preform a task. I had the code below with no luck. Would this statement not achieve this? This is using Qualcomm Gimbal technology that checks every .5 seconds. `visit.transmitter.name` will return a value right now every .5 seconds in this method.

```
    - (void)receivedSighting:(FYXVisit *)visit updateTime:(NSDate *)updateTime RSSI:(NSNumber *)RSSI;
{
if (visit.transmitter.name == nil) {
        [self showNoTransmittersView];
    }
}
```

Comment: There's not enough context to provide a good answer. The simple code you posted will call the `showNoTransmitterView` method if either `visit`, `visit.transmitter` or `visit.transmitter.name` are `nil`. But if `visit.transmitter.name` is the empty string (`@""`), it won't be called.

Comment: I think whether that works or not will depend on where visit.transmitter.name gets set -- to what, and how often. You'd need some explicit mechanism that checks every few seconds and resets to nil if necessary. How does a variable (as opposed to a method!) return something "every few seconds" ?

Comment: Have you used the debugger and checked if the `if` statement is being reached? If so, have you checked the value of `visit.transmitter.name`? Is it `nil` or something else?

Comment: OK, so `visit` is a parameter, an input to your function. What are you seeing that is not expected? Is this function getting called? Have you set a breakpoint and seen what the content of `visit` is each time? (Or even an NSLog()...)

Comment: @rmaddy lol great minds.

Comment: Like maddy mentioned, check for nil and for @"". Also, why is receivedSighting called from something that shouldn't exist?

Comment: Best way to check for nil and @"" is visit.transmitter.name.length > 0

Comment: @MatíasR In this case use `length == 0`.